# why do we need defaultValue, not just value in component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

A component library has an `<Input />` that accept props

defaultValue and value.

defaultValue is uncontrolled and value is controlled. But can't it always just be value? As a user there's no need to defaultValue

```
<Input value="something" />
```

using value prop will filled the value. So what's the reason using defaultValue?

Answer (score 1):

Setting the `defaultValue` prop sets the value during the initial load of the component. If you don't want to control the value of the field, you can make use of the `defaultValue` prop.

```
<input defaultValue="hello" />
```

However, when you provide the `value` prop to the `input` field, you are making it a controlled component. Now, if you want your user to change the value, you will have to add a `onChange` event handler so that you react to the changes and update the value.

```
const [value, setValue] = useState("hello");

<input 
  value={value} 
  onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)} 
/>
```

If you don't provide the `onChange` event handler and don't update the value, your user will never be able to update the field's value.

Comment: why can't I just do
`<input value="hello" />` and teat value as defaultValue?

Comment: @TinaGlenn That is what I have explained above. Try changing the value of the input field using your keyboard for both scenarios.

Comment: I get it but what's the point of defaultValue? no one need an input that don't change no? since value does the job, why need another prop like defaultValue?

Comment: You can think of it as an optional approach. You would either use `defaultValue` or you would use `value` and `onChange`. If you just provide `defaultValue` you can change the value using keyboard without having to add the `onChange` handler but if you provide `value`, you need to provide the `onChange` handler to react to user's keyboard events.